# Is it possible to add caption to an image using phonegap?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I'm trying to understand if phonegap can be used for local image manipulation. I'm looking to add a caption to an image from the camera roll and save the modified copy back in the camera roll.  For example I might have a picture of a cat in phone. I want to open it, add some lolcats style text and save the modified copy in the camera roll.

Is it possible to achieve this in phonegap?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use HTML5 Canvas to update the images and save it locally in your application space. However saving the image to the phone album is not straight forward. You may need to look at the below post to get the proper solution.

[How Can I Save An Image To An iPhone Photo Gallery Using PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663890/how-can-i-save-an-image-to-an-iphone-photo-gallery-using-phonegap)

This post will help you open the album image to canvas

[CameraRoll image to canvas using Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893741/cameraroll-image-to-canvas-using-phonegap)